# Time capsule backups previous versions of AppStore apps?

Tags: macos, time-machine, mac-appstore

I have an App that I bought from the AppStore but later the publisher started to distribute outside the AppStore.

I updated the application and when it stopped working I tried to find on my Time Machine backup with the surprise that it wasn't there. Only the actual one probably last backup.

That makes me think that Time Machine doesn't backup AppStore apps thats good if my current application was from the AppStore.

If this is correct. I'm hopping for way to mark thiss application to be included in all the backups.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange, I always backup all the entire hard disk even if they are AppStore apps.
So I am able to restore previous apps version.

Check if you have excluded some apps from backup.

[image]